# Does try close the file after if it is successful?

Tags: python, excel, spyder

I am trying to implement a quick code that checks to see if an Excel file is open.  When the file is open, the IOError works and tells me the file is open.  I can close and reopen the file at this point.  If I do not have the file open, and either by calling a subprocess.call() or simply clicking on it, I an error.

Why does the try corrupt it if there is no error raises?

I have tried to close the file after the try but this does not work either.

```
file_path = (r'C:\users\Desktop\Build-Temp.xlsx')

if os.path.exists(file_path) is True:
    report_closed = True
    try:
        report_opcl = open(file_path, 'w+')
#           report_opcl.close()
    except IOError:
        print("file open already")
        report_closed = False

#            if report_closed is True:
#            with report_opcl:
#                subprocess.call(file_path,shell=True)
```

Errors
Excel cannot open the file 'Build-Temp.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a file with `'w'` will delete the file contents. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) call this "truncating". You might avoid the corruption using `'a'` instead (not tested).

Anyway this is not going to work. By the time you check that `report_closed` is true another process might have opened the file.

I think you are trying to solve an unsolvable problem. There is no way to make sure that a file (identified by its path) will be available to another process in the future.

Comment: should I use the subprocess.call() in the scope of the try after close()?

Comment: I don't see how that could help. The world won't stop between `report_opcl.close()` and `subprocess.call(...)`, no matter what you do.